# debounce or throttle user input onKeyUp for a dropdown filter

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to implement de-bounce and throttle on user input on the search field for a drop-down filter.

I'm new to hooks, I'd de-bounced onChange functions of class components in a constructor but for some odd reason, hooks approach doesn't seem to work for me.

I tried many things referring to several posts on this, online. Had issues with the target value being null, fixed that but i don't feel like its de-bouncing or throttling user inputs at all.

I did use it directly onKeyUp={ e=>debounce(func, 2000) }, had issues with e being null

Please refer (https://mtsry.csb.app/) to get an idea of what I'm trying to achieve.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './dropdownfilter.css';

function DropDownFilter() {

    const [options, setOptions] = useState(['Mytidbit', 'Deepak', 'Wassup', 'Deeps', 'Maolins', 'Test']);

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const [deBounce, setDebounce] = useState(true);

    const debounce = (fn,delay) => {
        let timeId;
        return function(...args){
            if(timeId){
                clearTimeout(timeId);
            }

            timeId = setTimeout(()=>{
                fn(...args);
            }, delay);
        }
    };

    function throttle(fn, delay){
        let last = 0;

        return (...args)=>{
         const now = new Date().getTime();
         if(now-last < delay){
             return;
         }

          last = now;
          return fn(...args);
        }
     }

    const filterOptions = (e)=>{
        const optionsCopy = [...options];
        let filteredOptions = optionsCopy.filter(opt=>opt.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase()));
        setOptions(filteredOptions);
    };

    const debounceKeyUp = (e) => {
        e.persist();
        filterOptions(e);    
    };

    const throttleKeyUp = (e)=>{
         e.persist();
         filterOptions(e);
    };

    useEffect(()=>{
       debounce(debounceKeyUp, 2000);
       throttle(throttleKeyUp, 2000);
    },[]);

    const displayFilter = () => {
         setShow(!show);
    };

    const toggleFilter = ()=>{
        setDebounce(!deBounce)
    };

    return (
        <div className="dropdown">
            <button className="dropbtn" onClick={toggleFilter}>Change Filter Type</button><br/>
            <button onClick={displayFilter} className="dropbtn">{deBounce ? "DeBounce" : "Throttle"} <i className="arroww downn"></i></button>
            <div className={`dropdown-content ${show ? "show" : "hide"}`}>
                <input type="text" placeholder={deBounce ? "Try Debounce..." : "Try Throttle..."} className="filter-input" onKeyUp={deBounce ? e => {e.persist(); debounceKeyUp(e)} : e => {e.persist(); throttleKeyUp(e)}} />
                <i className="fa fa-fw fa-search" style={{position: 'relative', bottom: '34px', left: '5px'}}></i>
                {options.map((opt, i)=>(
                    <a key={i}>{opt}</a>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DropDownFilter;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to get instances of debounce and throttle function to use them. Unfortunately you are just calling debounce and throttle in useEffect but never use their returned function

You implementation doesn't need useEffect but useCallback like below

```
const debounceKeyUp = useCallback(debounce((e)=>{
     e.persist();
     filterOptions(e);
}, 2000), []);

const throttleKeyUp = useCallback(throttle((e)=>{
     e.persist();
     filterOptions(e);
}, 2000), []);
```

Complete code:

```js
function DropDownFilter() {

    const [options, setOptions] = useState(['Mytidbit', 'Deepak', 'Wassup', 'Deeps', 'Maolins', 'Test']);

    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const [deBounce, setDebounce] = useState(true);

    const debounce = (fn,delay) => {
        let timeId;
        return function(...args){
            if(timeId){
                clearTimeout(timeId);
            }

            timeId = setTimeout(()=>{
                fn(...args);
            }, delay);
        }
    };

    function throttle(fn, delay){
        let last = 0;

        return (...args)=>{
         const now = new Date().getTime();
         if(now-last < delay){
             return;
         }

          last = now;
          return fn(...args);
        }
     }

    const filterOptions = (e)=>{
        const optionsCopy = [...options];
        let filteredOptions = optionsCopy.filter(opt=>opt.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase()));
        setOptions(filteredOptions);
    };

    const debounceKeyUp = useCallback(debounce((e)=>{
         e.persist();
         filterOptions(e);
    }, 2000), []);

    const throttleKeyUp = useCallback(throttle((e)=>{
         e.persist();
         filterOptions(e);
    }, 2000), []);

    const displayFilter = () => {
         setShow(!show);
    };

    const toggleFilter = ()=>{
        setDebounce(!deBounce)
    };

    return (
        <div className="dropdown">
            <button className="dropbtn" onClick={toggleFilter}>Change Filter Type</button><br/>
            <button onClick={displayFilter} className="dropbtn">{deBounce ? "DeBounce" : "Throttle"} <i className="arroww downn"></i></button>
            <div className={`dropdown-content ${show ? "show" : "hide"}`}>
                <input type="text" placeholder={deBounce ? "Try Debounce..." : "Try Throttle..."} className="filter-input" onKeyUp={deBounce ? e => {e.persist(); debounceKeyUp(e)} : e => {e.persist(); throttleKeyUp(e)}} />
                <i className="fa fa-fw fa-search" style={{position: 'relative', bottom: '34px', left: '5px'}}></i>
                {options.map((opt, i)=>(
                    <a key={i}>{opt}</a>
                ))}
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}

export default DropDownFilter;
```

Comment: Yes Makes sense....I wasn't using the reference of de-bounce or throttle. This resolved my issue..Thanks....upvoted

Comment: Glad to have helped